# SWRevealViewController Disappears table cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Im using `SWRevealViewController`[from](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) github, And i add table view as child view of main View Controller

```
newPageView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"eventsVC")

outerContainer.addSubview(newPageView!.view)
```

`UITableView` loads with data but when i touch the table view all cells disappearing from dable.

[image: IB]

Before Touch
[image: Before Touch]

After Touch
[image: After Touch]

Comment: are you adding the tableview to the child of SWRevealViewController?

Comment: @Arun yes, im adding uiview (ectracted from UITableViewController) to on of the `sw_front` Segue ViewController.

Comment: Please check the my updated question.

Comment: did you give the segue identifier correctly as mentioned in the sample.There are two identifier 1.sw_rear 2.sw_front

Comment: Yes, I'm sure i have done this part correctly, everything ok, but this issue.

Comment: when you press the 3bar icon buuton try to load a tableviewcontroller.do load a tableview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133542/discussion-between-arun-and-wimal-weerawansa).

Comment: I already doing this.

Comment: attach the sample complete code you have integrated this.not your project